# I just heard that Kaddish is said for only 100 years after someone dies

Tags: death, time, kaddish

I just heard that Kaddish is said for only 100 years after someone dies. Has anyone else heard this opinion and does anyone know why? This situation occurred as my grandmothers 100 yaherzeit is coming up and i was told you don't say Kaddish for more than 99 years.

Comment: Uh, I thought we said Kaddish for only eleven months after someone died, not one hundred years. What do you mean here?

Comment: [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! Could you please [edit] the body of this post to have a more fleshed-out version of the question? Where did you hear of this concept? What do you know about kaddish that makes you wonder about this idea? etc.

Comment: Do you mean Yahrtzeits? Maybe the rule is there because otherwise we'd say Kaddish every day for our ancestors' Yahrtzeits. Every day is some ancestor's Yahrtzeit by now. @ezra

Comment: @DoubleAA  isn't that why we never say tachanun, because it's always some rebbe's yahrzeit?

Comment: @alex I don't know who you mean by "we" but they clearly wouldn't be following traditional Judaism which hadn't obsolesced Tachanun even after the death of 1.2 million prophets seemingly on every day of the year

Comment: @DoubleAA  B.B. 12a חכם עדיף מנביא

Comment: @alex lol `:-)`

Comment: Possibly related to Avot 5:23 - a 100 year person is considered as if he is dead. Well, an already dead person would be dead "twice" 100 years later? That makes no sense.

Comment: I also have a personal interest in a definitive answer to this question, three of the yahrzeits I observe (grandparents) are already well past 50 years (related question), one grandparent's yahrzeit will reach 100 years in my lifetime, and my mother's yahrzeit will reach 50 years soon.

Answer (score 3):

It is sometimes quoted that Kadish and / or Yahrtzeit are not kept longer than 50 (not 100) years after the deceased's passing.
Yet, The ספר ציץ אליעזר חלק יד' סימן עה, סעיף ב and ספר ציוני הלכה הלכות אבלות - Authored by הרב בן ציון הכהן קוק - in the name of R' Yosef Shalom Elyashiv, and  R' Ovadia Yosef ספר חזון עובדיה על הלכות אבלות חלק ג' (עמודים רלז-רלח) all say that Kaddish and Yohrzeit are kept for even much longer.